# Promises in Class Diagramm

Tags: typescript, promise, uml, future

iam using the programming language `typescript` with `nodejs`.
Well i just want to know how to deal with promises in a class diagramm.
I got much interfaces with async method only (returning promises).

example of the interface:

```
interface Connection{
    obtainStatus(): Promise<Status>;
    ...
}
```

Whats the best practice to deal with promises in a class diagramm?
Should I simple write `Promise<...>` everywhere?

Answer (score 1):

Promises are just a way to say that you have something that
may eventually become a value. But, as far as I know, there
isn't any conventions on how to represent them in class
diagras.

Also, considering that people generally want a class diagram
to reasonably represent the business logic of the program,
I imagine two options.

Assuming they are common enough in JavaScript land, you
could come up with a special notation to denote that method
returns a promise value, and spread that notion to your
team.

What I would do is simply skip promises when representing
the relationships between the objects in your diagram, as
they are just a detail of implementation.